# rsync does not create a directory backup

Tags: backup, rsync

Let's say that I have a directory with files:

```
a b c d
```

So I copy with rsync:

```
rsync -av --delete -P --backup --backup-dir=sample-$(date +%a-%H%M) ../sample /backups
```

I get in /backup/sample:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 sergio sergio 0 feb 17 18:31 d
-rw-r--r-- 1 sergio sergio 0 feb 17 18:31 c
-rw-r--r-- 1 sergio sergio 0 feb 17 18:31 b
-rw-r--r-- 1 sergio sergio 0 feb 17 18:31 a
```

But if I create a directory:

```
a b c d newdir
```

I only get in /backup/sample:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 sergio sergio    0 feb 17 18:31 d
-rw-r--r-- 1 sergio sergio    0 feb 17 18:31 c
-rw-r--r-- 1 sergio sergio    0 feb 17 18:31 b
-rw-r--r-- 1 sergio sergio    0 feb 17 18:31 a
drwxr-xr-x 2 sergio sergio 8192 feb 17 18:52 newdir
```

However if I delete a file:

```
/backups
├── sample
│   ├── a
│   ├── b
│   ├── c
│   └── newdir
└── sample-sáb-1855
    └── sample
        └── d
```

So, why does rsync not create a 'sample-date...' in the first modification (creation of newdir).
Is that the expected bahaviour?

Answer (score 1):

From [`rsync(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rsync.1.html)

> **-b, --backup**
>                 With this option, *preexisting destination files* are renamed as
>                 each file is transferred or deleted.  You can control where
>                 the backup file goes and what (if any) suffix gets appended
>                 using the **--backup-dir** and **--suffix** options.

At the first two times, only new files are transferred, and so there is no need for creating backups.

At the third call, file `sample/d` is removed, and now the option `--backup` tells rsync to create a backup of `sample/d`. This backup is created in the backup directory `/backups` + `sample-$(date +%a-%H%M)`.

The same would happen, if you modify any of the existing files. E.g. changing the file `sample/a`, would create a backup copy of `a` in the backup directory `/backups/sample-$(date +%a-%H%M)`.

---

If you want to create a versioned backup, you would rather give a different target directory each time rsync runs

```
rsync -av --delete -P ../sample /backups/sample-$(date +%a-%H%M)
```